# How to use material-ui-pickers KeyboardDatePicker with moment?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, momentjs

I am using `KeyBoardDatePicker` from `material-ui-pickers` with `moment utils` for a DatePicker.

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import {
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
  KeyboardDatePicker
} from "@material-ui/pickers";
import MomentUtils from "@date-io/moment";
import moment from "moment";

function KeyboardDatePickerExample(props) {
  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(new Date());

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <MuiPickersUtilsProvider libInstance={moment} utils={MomentUtils}>
        <KeyboardDatePicker
          autoOk={true}
          showTodayButton={true}
          value={selectedDate}
          format="D MMM, YYYY"
          onChange={handleDateChange}
          minDate={moment().subtract(6, "months")}
          maxDate={moment()}
        />
      </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default KeyboardDatePickerExample;
```

But it's not working properly.

First, it's not showing the date format properly

[image: Initial view of the picker]

and when I try to edit, it it's showing random text and an error `invalid date format`.

[image: View of the picker when I try to edit]

Here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-snow-obgzt?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) that reproduces the issue.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**:

After seeing the answer by Nico, I changed the version of `date-io/moment` to `1.3.13`

Now, the date format is displayed properly

[image]

But the edit propblem still exists. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Did you manage to solve the edit problem?

Comment: @an0o0nym I posted an answer. Please have a look

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is the fix provided by a colleague of mine. He used `inputValue` and `value` props of `KeyboardDatePicker`. `value` takes date object and `inputValue` takes formatted date string. And also used `rifmFormatter` prop as follows to fix the edit issue. I have also updated the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/long-pond-wfuof?file=/src/App.js:0-1001)

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import {
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
  KeyboardDatePicker
} from "@material-ui/pickers";
import MomentUtils from "@date-io/moment";
import moment from "moment";

function KeyboardDatePickerExample(props) {
  const [selectedDate, setDate] = useState(moment());
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"));

  const onDateChange = (date, value) => {
    setDate(date);
    setInputValue(value);
  };

  const dateFormatter = str => {
    return str;
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <MuiPickersUtilsProvider libInstance={moment} utils={MomentUtils}>
        <KeyboardDatePicker
          autoOk={true}
          showTodayButton={true}
          value={selectedDate}
          format="YYYY-MM-DD"
          inputValue={inputValue}
          onChange={onDateChange}
          rifmFormatter={dateFormatter}
        />
      </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default KeyboardDatePickerExample;
```

Comment: thank you for posting your answer! I noticed that problem in my case is that I have a `KeyboardDatePicker` inside mui's `Dialog`. I believe this re-renders the Dialog component somehow on a date change causing the error. However everything works just fine when `KeyboardDatePicker` is outside the mui's `Dialog` component. I post this comment just in case someone has similar problem.

Comment: <flame>Please allow a small flame -- as nearly as I can tell, this entire environment is a massive job-and-income-security effort created by programmers for programmers.

I got here in March of 2021 because I want what I thought was a simple and easy widget -- a date picker that depicts a given date as '03/12/2021'. I think that is a format string of "mm/dd/yyyy" in any reasonable component in any language that handles dates. I've been at this for nearly a day now with no joy.

BTW, it does NOT work with the above code.

Is this REALLY the best that we can do?
</flame>

Answer (score 5):

You can't use material UI picker **v3** and @date-io/moment **v2** together. You have to use the **v1.x** version of @date-io/moment.

Here is some more information about this topic:
https://material-ui-pickers.dev/getting-started/installation

Best regards
Nico

Comment: I changed the version of `date-io/moment` to `1.3.13`. Now, the date format is displayed properly but the edit problem still exists. How can I fix that?

Comment: Does MUI Core v5.0.0 also require v1.x version of @date-io/moment ? In MUI Core v5.0.0, @material-ui/pickers moved to @mui/lab but I do not see any information at
 https://mui.com/components/date-picker/ about the compatibility with any particular version of @date-io/moment .

Answer (score 2):

@troglodyte07 's answer fixed the issue of date formatting. However, the caret is going backward when typing English characters or commas. It is because the default date format does not accept English characters and special characters like commas.

The edit issue can be fixed by setting rifmFormatter and refuse properties to override the default date format. For example, to edit date with this date format "D MMM, YYYY", we need to set rifmFormatter and refuse properties by the regular expressions which allow English characters, commas, spaces, and numbers.

```
/[^ ,a-zA-Z0-9]+/gi
```

For other date formats, the regular expressions should be customized.

I have forked @troglodyte07 's sandbox and improved it: [datepicker-edit-value-custom-format](https://codesandbox.io/s/datepicker-edit-value-custom-format-cy41b7?file=/src/App.js)

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import {
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
  KeyboardDatePicker
} from "@material-ui/pickers";
import MomentUtils from "@date-io/moment";
import moment from "moment";

function KeyboardDatePickerExample(props) {
  const [selectedDate, setDate] = useState(moment());
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(moment().format("D MMM, YYYY"));

  const onDateChange = (date, value) => {
    setDate(date);
    setInputValue(value);
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <MuiPickersUtilsProvider libInstance={moment} utils={MomentUtils}>
        <KeyboardDatePicker
          autoOk={true}
          showTodayButton={true}
          value={selectedDate}
          format="D MMM, YYYY"
          inputValue={inputValue}
          onChange={onDateChange}
          rifmFormatter={(val) => val.replace(/[^ ,a-zA-Z0-9]+/gi, "")}
          refuse={/[^ ,a-zA-Z0-9]+/gi}
        />
      </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default KeyboardDatePickerExample;
```